# javascript - sort by the order of a second array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

Given:

```
var a1 = [{name:'Scott'}, {name:'John'}, {name:'Albert'}];
var sortOrder = ['John', 'Scott', 'Albert'];
```

How can I sort the first array (by property) based on the order specified in the second array.

```
// result: [{name:'John'}, {name:'Scott'}, {name:'Albert'}]
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
a1.sort(function(a,b) {
  return (
    sortOrder.indexOf(a.name) < sortOrder.indexOf(b.name) ? -1 : 1
  );
});
```

Comment: That was what I was in the middle of typing... +1

Comment: Only issue here is that IE doesn't support `indexOf()`, so you'll need to create an `indexOf()` function for it: http://stellapower.net/content/javascript-support-and-arrayindexof-ie

Comment: @Gert G: either that, or make IE work 'properly' using [Chrome Frame](http://code.google.com/chrome/chromeframe/) ;)

Comment: It worked for me, but I have to changed to a1.sort(function(a,b) { return (sortOrder.indexOf(a.name) < sortOrder.indexOf(b.name) ) ? -1 : 1;});